# Custom package using parallel or doParallel for multiple OS as a CRAN package

Tags: r, parallel-processing, cran

I am building a package for R which I want to be able to be cross-platform. I am developing under Linux, and the function `mclapply` will be used from the `parallel` package. This package is not supported for Windows (which uses `doParallel`). I really like the `parallel` package though for it's simplicity and speed, and I do not know if this should be a reason to have 2 different versions available of the package for CRAN, for the separate OS (seems like extra work to maintain), not to mention if it is even allowed.

Thoughts?

Also, for now I am regarding `parallel`'s

```
mclapply(ldata, function(x), mc.cores=cores)
```

to be equivalent of `doParallel`'s

```
cl <- makeCluster(cores)
parLapply(cl, ldata, function(x))
```

Is that correct?

Comment: Why not use the `parLapply` also from the `parallel` package as I believe this is cross platform (or I hope it is since I use it in one of my packages).  You can also use an `if(){}else{}` with `Sys.info()["sysname"]` to use the correct setup.

Comment: @Tyler Rinker, does the parLapply show the .Rprofile loading for every new script? If yes, then I think it should be good since it isn't fork.

Comment: `parallel` **is** supported on windows, and `mclapply` can be used. It just reverts to serial evaluation, like a simple `lapply`.

Comment: @MartinMorgan But then that is not the desired fallback behavior unfortunately...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, both `mclapply` and `parLapply` are in the `parallel` package, although `mclapply` doesn't actually run in parallel on Windows.  `parLapply` runs in parallel on all supported platforms, but isn't always as efficient as `mclapply`.  The `doParallel` package is used with the `foreach` package, and acts as an adapter to the `parallel` package.

To write a package that works on both Windows and non-Windows, you have a variety of reasonable options:

- Just use `parLapply` since it works everywhere
- Use `parLapply` on Windows and `mclapply` elsewhere
- Use `doParallel` with `foreach`

The `doParallel` package is convenient because it makes use of `mclapply` on non-Windows platforms.  For example:

```
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel()
foreach(i=1:10, .options.snow=list(preschedule=TRUE)) %dopar% {
    Sys.sleep(2)
}
```

This uses `mclapply` on Linux and Mac OS X, but will automatically create a PSOCK cluster object behind the scenes on Windows.  The use of `preschedule=TRUE` (added in `doParallel` 1.0.3) will cause `doParallel` to *preschedule* the tasks using `clusterApply` internally, much like `parLapply`.

Note that if you explicitly create and register a cluster object, then `mclapply` will *not* be used, regardless of the platform.  It will work fine, but may not be as efficient.  To use `mclapply`, you must call `registerDoParallel` with a numeric argument, or no argument at all.

You can look at the source code for the `boot` package for an example of how to use either `mclapply` or `parLapply` depending on your platform.